# input mask behaving oddly

Tags: microsoft-access, input, mask

I am using Access 2010. I have created an input mask 0000\B?. The resultant should be 4 numbers, the letter B and an optional 2nd letter, ie 1234Bx. My problem is the ?. Any time the optional letter is a B (resulting in BB) Access discards the optional letter. Is there a syntax issue I'm not aware of?